# How to prevent fridge freezer drain from freezing over?

Tags: refrigerator, freezing

I have a Samsung fridge freezer, with fridge on the top. The drain pipe in the fridge that lets the condensation out freezes near the bottom (near the freezer part) and blocks after just 2 days since I defrosted it. So then the drain overflows and a big pool of water at the bottom of the fridge. Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a way to fix it, or is it time for a new fridge?

EDIT:
The model is a Samsung RL26DCAS. The drain pipe that is causing the issue is pretty much inaccessible. You can access the end of the pipe from a removable panel on the back of the freezer. but the part of the pipe that is frozen is slightly higher than this, and the only way to access it would be to take a saw to the metal panel on the back. I will try and add a picture later if I can.

Comment: I have this exact same problem with my Samsung fridge (french door, fridge on top, drawer freezer). Water pools and freezes under the dairy drawer. The drain pipe behind a panel at the back is gunk-clogged, and if you squeeze its nozzle, it flushes. I removed the nozzle and it helps, but this is not the solution of course.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a rubber drain line that goes from the bottom of the condensate tray in the back of the freezer (probably behind an access panel), out the bottom of the refig, to the drain pan that's under the refrig.  That drain line can get clogged with dust/dirt or spider webs.  When this happens, the water can't flow out of the freezer, backs up into the freezer, and freezes.

You need to get to that rubber drain tube and clear it out.  But first you have to get rid of the ice that's blocking it.

There should be information on line as to how to do this for your particular model refrigerator.  On some you can access this from the freezer comparment.  But on others you need to in through the back of the refrig to get to the drain line.

**Added Picture**

Here is picture from https://www.applianceblog.com, that shows the condensate pan on a typical Samsung freezer, showing the ice buildup that results from a clogged drain tube.  The drain tube comes out in the center (usually) of the pan that's covered in ice in that picture.

[image]

Comment: I agree cleaning may be needed, I have not closed the door tight and lots of water and a little crud make a mess.

Comment: This doesn't really look like the fridge freezer I have.

Answer (score 0):

Getting clogged pipe with dirt is unusual. Defrosting system may be broken and ice is blocking the pipe. Check that system. It is motorized clock, heater and thermorelay.

Comment: If the defrost cycle wasn't working, there would be frost/ice all over the refrigerant coils.  The fact that the frost is melting, then refreezing in the tray tells me the defrost cycle is working just fine.

Comment: I am writing about possible case. You may be right but not for sure if you do not see it by your own . You are  guessing just like me. Only OP knows what's going on.