# Why there’s a black rubber cap that perfectly lodges in the Kenmore refrigerator’s drain tube?

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator

My Kenmore refrigerator is forming a thin sheet of ice every 2 or 3 days at the bottom of the freezer. I watched this [video on youtube](https://youtu.be/5eR_JXmrGpQ) which is exactly the problem I’m encountering. She made fixing this problem looked easy.

I checked the drain tube (a blue arrow points to the drain tube and the location where the black rubber cap clogs the drain tube) and found that it’s clogged with a black rubber cap.

[image]

Is the black rubber cap part of the refrigerator interior? Does it need to go somewhere inside the refrigerator? Or I can throw it away and be done with the the ice sheet issue?

[image]

I’ve added the model number of the refrigerator here

[image]

The refrigerator does have a drain pan. After I removed the rubber cap from the drain tube, it’s already accumulating water. I have added a [video of the pan](https://www.veed.io/view/cba9f77a-e69e-4e84-b5a7-737c635e0ecf).

Comment: Looks like the caps that come on refrigeration linesets. Someone at the factory was crap at policing their garbage. It doesn't look like w/e duck-drain thing she *also didn't* have. Hers was just full of junk.

Answer (score 1):

From what you've told us, that black cap should not be there.  The water that's formed when the frost melts during the defrost cycle collects in a pan at the bottom of the freezer and then drains out through that tube to a drain pan under the refrig.  From there the water evaporates.

Here's a link to an answer I posted to a similar problem:

[How to prevent fridge freezer drain from freezing over?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/223153/how-to-prevent-fridge-freezer-drain-from-freezing-over/223154#223154)